# How can I extract specific time components out of a UTCTime?

Tags: haskell

If I have this code:

`let time = read "2013-02-03 17:00:07.687" :: UTCTime`

How can I extract the minutes and seconds components out of the `UTCTime`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `UTCTime` has two components: a day and a `DiffTime`. You can get the `DiffTime` using `utctDayTime` or by pattern matching. From there, you can convert it to a [`TimeOfDay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.4/doc/html/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#t%3aTimeOfDay) using [`timeToTimeOfDay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.4/doc/html/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#v%3atimeToTimeOfDay). You can then just pattern match against the `TimeOfDay` to get the hours, minutes and seconds.

So you could do this:

```
let TimeOfDay hours minutes seconds = timeToTimeOfDay (utctDayTime time)
```

You can also use the `todMin` and `todSec` functions to get the minutes and seconds respectively out of the `TimeOfDay`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [time-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-lens) package, which makes time and date manipulation much easier. E.g.

```
> let time = read "2013-02-03 17:00:07.687" :: UTCTime
> getL seconds time
7.687000000000
```

If you import `Data.Lens.Common`, there's also an infix version of `getL`:

```
> time ^. minutes
0
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've wanted this package before, but did not know it existed!